Need of personal Ledger device
The question is regarding cryptocurrencies. There have been many cases of fraud and theft over time and the recommended approach is to transfer funds to a physical personal ledger device. Hoever the trading platform I use is using the Ledger Vault solution in their backend to secure funds.
Considering that I am mostly investing for short time, is it safe to trust the trading platform or should I still transfer to a personal Ledger with according transfer fees?

Crypto is just fraud.  Get out.

Some would say the recommended approach is to not participate.  "Even Gronk know this not real money"

Most big country governments have invested a lot in bitcoin. Are you saying they should all exit the market?

@M.Parent Most big country governments have invested a lot in bitcoin - citation needed.

Most big countries own a lot of gold too. Doesn't mean it's necessarily always a good investment for regular individuals.

Due to the unregulated nature of crypto, I would be very suspicious of any exchange's claims that they can 100% protect your money. Hacking is VERY common especially since crypto is essentially anonymous. On top of that, crypto exchanges are rarely insured against the worst types of user losses. From an associate of insurance commissioners (NAIC):

Though insurance protections do exist for cryptocurrency, they are far
from comprehensive, and generally won’t cover losses from issues such
as market fluctuations, Ponzi-related schemes, direct hardware loss,
and cryptocurrency losses related to various blockchain failures.

If you keep the tokens on a hardware wallet you still run the risk of:

Rug pulls or other fraud making the tokens go to $0
Losing the device or the device failing

A better alternative might be to utilize crypto ETFs such as Fidelity's as those are more established (larger, older coins) and "safer".
Aside: I would think carefully about adding crypto to your portfolio. This is akin to buying individual stocks but they are WAY more prone to fraud and not based on any tangible assets. Personally I would only buy more established coins like Bitcoin and not let it get larger than a few % of my portfolio.
